# I want to combine first function to the second one, so I can call it only once

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I want to combine first function to the second one, so I can call it only once. Basically i have 2 html5 audio files that im playing. Everything works fine.But if i play my first audio and during that time if i click the second audio the pause button on first audio doesn't change to default(off)

```
//First function 

function toggleState(item) {
  if (item.className == "play") {
    item.className = "pause";
  } else {
    item.className = "play";
  }
}

//Second function
// Play stop Music
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
  var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
  if (thissound.paused) {
    thissound.play();
  } else {
    thissound.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by combining can you give an example +1 for using pure js rather than some weird libraries btw

Comment: It's  for audio files basically. I need an on/of state of the play and pause buttons.With one function only it doesn't work as i wanted. So i need to mix both to achieve the result.

Comment: So you want to toggle the play/pause functionality and the play/pause class-names? In these functions do the `soundobj` and the `item` variables refer to the same thing?

Comment: Yes. Cause i have 2 audio files and if i click play on first one, it plays. But during that time if i click the second audio, the audio plays fine, but on the first one the pause buttons doesn't change to default state.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question, to add the relevant ("[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)") HTML of this part of your page?

Comment: do u want when u click an audio if theres any other on playing state to be paused ?

Comment: Look at the example i made. Basically i need to switch between states.So if i play audio 1 audio 2 stops, and vice versa.http://codepen.io/ssddayz/pen/xGerQa

Comment: Well i managed to fix the issue Have a look please, and tell me what do you think. The sample is at codepen.

Comment: Add a common class to all inputs that control audio. Let's say "audioControl". Then in the function that toggles `play` first find all elements by class name, `pause` all of them, and then play the one that was clicked. This way you will be able to easily extend number of elements displayed on page

Comment: @istref: Please remove the edits from your question and add an answer describing the solution that you arrived at explaining how it solved your problem. Question should remain as a problem. You can self-answer and accept your own answer too.

Comment: Man , I'm new in editing posts. I get so confused writing it. Please forgive me. I always post an answer to my question. The solution. Not sure what you mean. Writing , editing a post for the end user should be plain and simple.

Comment: The principle is that the question should be in the 'question' (which it is) but your solution should be an 'answer,' so we'd expect you to [edit] your question, to remove the 'solution,' and move that 'solution' into an  'answer.' That way the engine recognises that there is an answer, and you can accept that answer and mark the question as having been answered.

Comment: Sigh. Why do these "unanswered" questions remain in a state where the author doesn't answer and close it. So annoying.

Answer (score 0):

*This question was answered in question by its owner with the following solution:*

I Managed to fixed it like this.

```
function toggleState(item, soundobj) {
  var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
  if (item.className == "play") {
  thissound.play();
  item.className = "pause";
 } else {
  thissound.pause();
  item.className = "play";  
 }
}
```

I Also managed to get the current track list title. For Example, you click on a song and it will display after , say like "Now playing blablabla song".

I show you a working example below.

**HTML:**

```
<option id="1" title="Now Playing." value="URL.mp3">Song name</option>
```

**Javascript:**

```
audioURL = document.getElementById('mylist');
var f = audioURL.options[audioURL.selectedIndex].title; //Here is title  
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = f; //output to f at demo elem.
```